# mysql aggregation with the max length

Tags: mysql, sql, max, aggregation

This my table

```
prefix | rate   | provider
------------------------
21366  | 0.1951 | ES
213    | 0.0554 | ES
213    | 0.0567 | 3LV
2136   | 0.189  | 3LV
213    | 0.0481 | vbP
21366  | 0.1894 | vbP
44     | 0.05   | ES
44     | 0.004  | vbP
```

How can | select the lowest rate for prefix X with the max length of a prefix between all providers.

for example for this prefix 21366
The result set should look like that

```
2136   | 0.189  | 3LV - The Winner
21366  | 0.1894 | vbP
21366  | 0.1951 | ES
```

If the provider has the exact prefix 21366  then it will be the row that will be compared with the other providers' rates. If the provider doesn't have the exact prefix, then we try to find the longest common string between wanted prefix and the provider's prefixes.

I use this condition to match prefixes `WHERE 21366 LIKE CONCAT(` prefix `,  '%' )`

So first, find the prefix each provider. Then select the lowest rate between the providers

Comment: Try searching for help on the "groupwise maximum" problem. It's already well documented across the web.

Comment: can you talk about how you determine your "prefix"  Because to me if you used `21366` in your example, I have no idea why `0.0481` (corresponding to `213`) is not your answer.  What determines what is considered a "prefix" for a given value? In other words, why is `2136` in your results and not `213`?  Is it the given value or the given value minus one character? This is really the challenge in trying to answer your question, as it seems to be arbitrary how you decided `2136` is in your result set and `213` is not.

Comment: @Lee This isn't the groupwise max problem! Or am I missing something?

Comment: If the provider has the exact prefix 21366 then it will be the row that will be compared with the other providers' rates. If the provider doesn't have the exact prefix, then we try to find the longest common string between wanted prefix and the provider's prefixes.

Comment: @nullException If that is the issue then why did you search for 2136 when two exact matches were already found for 21366? You should have chosen between the two rows with prefix 21366 which had the min value for rate. Please elaborate.

Comment: the problem is solved. you can take a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-cost_routing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should return the rows that you need:

```
SELECT tablename.*
FROM
  tablename INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      provider, MAX(LENGTH(prefix)) as max_length
    FROM
      tablename
    WHERE
      '21366' LIKE CONCAT(prefix, '%')
    GROUP BY
      provider) m
  ON tablename.provider = m.provider
     AND LENGTH(prefix)=m.max_length
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20e96/1). You might also want to add this to your query:

```
ORDER BY
  rate
LIMIT 1
```

if you just need the lowest rate.